# How to license my wordpress plugin after development under GPL?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I have created a wordpress plugin but I have no knowledge of licensing. I have already read the wordpress article - "[Including a Software License](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/including-a-software-license/)" under wordpress plugin handbook.

Do I need to just write following lines in Header section? -

```
{Plugin Name} is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 2...

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with {Plugin Name}. If not, see {URI to Plugin License}.
```

Is anything else also required like signing up on GPL site or buying some subscription?

Answer (score 3):

> Here's a brief summary of what you need to do to release a program under one of our licenses:
>
> - Get a copyright disclaimer from your employer or school.
> - Give each file the proper copyright notices. Make sure to clearly identify which versions of the license users can use.
> - Add a COPYING file with a copy of the GNU GPL or GNU AGPL.
> - Also add a COPYING.LESSER file with a copy of the GNU LGPL, if you use that.
> - Put a license notice in each file.
> - (Optionally) make the program display a startup notice.
> - (If using the AGPL) make the program offer copies of its source code.
>
> This involves adding two elements to each source file of your program: a copyright notice (such as “Copyright 1999 Terry Jones”), and a statement of copying permission, saying that the program is distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License (or the Lesser GPL, or the Affero GPL).
>
> -- Source: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.en.html

The page then gives a more detailed explanation of each bullet.

The license notice mentioned above could have the form of the comment block given on the wordpress page you linked to.

There is no need to register anything nor are there any subscriptions or fees to pay.